# Couchbase Cluster and Bucket management

Tags: java, couchbase, database-administration

I am developing a server-side app using Java and couchbase. I am trying to understand the pros and cons of handling the cluster and bucket management from the java code over using the couchbase admin web console.

For instance, should I handle create/ remove buckets, indexing, and update buckets in my java code?

The reason I want to handle as many as couchbase administration functions is my app is expected to run on-prem not a cloud services. I want to avoid that our customers need to learn how to administrate couchbase.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason to use the management APIs programmatically, rather than using the admin console, is exactly as you say: when you need to handle initializing and maintaining yourself, especially if the application needs to be deployed elsewhere. Generally speaking, you'll want to have some sort of database initializer or manager module in your code, which handles bootstrapping the correct buckets and indexes if they don't exist.

If all you need to do is handle preparing the DB environment one time for your application, you can also use the command line utilities that come with Couchbase, or send calls to the REST API. A small deployment script would probably be easier than writing code to do the same thing.

Comment: I like the idea of using a deployment script.